# Can a copyright owner grant additional permission for another project to use under a different license?

Tags: licensing, gpl, relicensing

Can a copyright holder of a GPL licensed project grant permission to allow another project to use it under the terms of a different license?

The GNU/GPL is a copyleft license, which means that derivative work can only be distributed under the same license terms [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License].

For example, the copyright owner of a project under a GPL license could grant permission to a project that uses a license such as MIT or BSD to distribute their work (in whole or in part) under that more permissive license. If this is allowed, are there any caveats to doing this?

Comment: Do you know of [tag:multi-licensing]?

Comment: I'm aware that a project can have multiple licences. My question focuses on the specific case of one project allowing an exception specifically for another project to include its source code.

Comment: Not well versed in this, but afaik the answer is yes, *but* it requires the *express* permission of *all* copyright holders - which means everyone and anyone who has ever contributed something to the project, no matter how small. So for example if you have accepted pull requests to "your" GPL project then you need express written permission from that author too. (Mozilla did this when they changed license and it took *many many years*.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can release your intellectual property to different people under different license conditions. This is not just permissible, it is a common business model commonly known as [multi-licensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-licensing). It is not uncommon to release a GPL-licensed version of a software gratis, but also offer a paid version under a license which allows to distribute derivative works under proprietary licenses.

This business model works well for frameworks, middleware, libraries and other software which is usually used as a base to develop other applications. With the GPL-version, those other applications must also be GPL-licensed, which limits the monetization options. But when you buy the proprietary license, you have far more options, including pay-by-install.

The MIT and BSD are rarely a good choice for this business model, though, because they allow redistribution under the same terms. So anyone you sell a BSD or MIT license to would then be able to underbid you. A paid license for an open source project usually does not allow to relicense the sourcecode of the derivatives to other parties.

Still, you see software multi-licensed under GPL, MIT and/or BSD. So if you don't feel like taking sides in the endless discussion about which open source license is the most free one, you can simply let people choose under which software license they prefer to use your software.

Comment: That is why selling support is the root of profit. Others can underbid, but large corporations doesn't like taking chances when it comes to professional support - and presumably the original authors can provide the best support and an entity that is merely underbidding / reselling is less trustworthy. So I think that's why we see GPL + MIT in some cases - others can copy the product but they can not copy trust.

Comment: One minor nitpick (or misunderstanding on my part): "MIT and BSD are rarely a good choice for this business model, though, because they allow redistribution under the same terms" -- isn't the problem here actually the opposite, i.e., they allow distribution/modification under *different* (less permissive) terms? The GPL allows distribution under the same terms as well, but disallows distribution under different terms.

Comment: @apsillers What I thought about is the following scenario: 1. you sell your product under GPL for free but for $100 under MIT, 2. you find some customers who buy the MIT version for $100 3. one of your customers then offers the MIT version for less than $100 4. nobody buys from you anymore because they can get it cheaper from your customer. So when you do dual-licensing, make sure the paid license does not allow your customers to drive you off the market with your own product.

Comment: @Philipp your answer is fine, but the question has no mention of commercial licensing options. I am upvoting nonetheless!

Comment: @Philipp The scenario you mention is impossible. When you offer something under an MIT, BSD, or GPL license, that license automatically applies to anyone and everyone. You automatically hold an MIT license to everything ever offered under an MIT license, and ditto for BSD and GPL.  If you think about it, this must be the case. Otherwise, how would you ever get a GPL license to something? Say you get the source code from a friend who has no connection to the author. The friend can't give you the license, so you must have already had it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That's a common misconception. OS software is *often* licensed to the whole world by putting it on a public webserver. But you can also license it to only one specific person. That other person then holds a license but *can* give other people a license if they want to. See [this](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#DoesTheGPLAllowMoney) and [this](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#CanIDemandACopy) entry for the GPL FAQ.  If you have further questions about this, please open a new question.

Comment: @Philipp Putting software on a webserver doesn't license it. Placing it under a license does. And you cannot license something under the GPL to only one person, and none of the entries in the GPL FAQ say that. And that *can't* be right. If it were right, say I was the only person who had a GPL license and I distributed the code to Jeff. How could Jeff distribute it since he doesn't have a GPL license? And I sure can't give him one since I'm not the author. The misconception is entirely on your side here. If code is under a GPL license, everyone has that license.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You really seem to be confused about how licensing work. A license can be *transferable*. Most proprietary licenses don't allow to transfer the license to someone else. But open source licenses do. When you receive a work under an open source license you also get the permission to license it to other people under the same condition. That's what share-alike means.

Comment: @Philipp If the GPL were transferable, that would mean that someone who transferred a copy of a covered work no longer had a license. That's now how the GPL was ever understood and this was made explicit in the GPLv3 which states that the license comes from the original author. If what you said were right, how would you know you actually had a GPL license? Unless the "you" in the GPL means everyone, how would anyone know whether it applied to them? I assure you, you are the one who is confused. The license always comes from the original author.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz This leads nowhere.

Comment: @Philipp I'm just trying to make sure you don't confuse people. What you are saying is 100% wrong and, bluntly, nonsensical. When I read in the GPL that "You may convey verbatim copies of the Program's source code as you receive it" -- unless that "you" means everyone, how do I know that *I* actually have a license? A work is either offered by its original authors under the GPL license or it isn't.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz should we start a chat on this?
Note that you wrote: "When you offer something under an MIT, BSD, or GPL license, that license automatically applies to anyone and everyone." 
I know of a commercial vendor that did relicense on a request to only one of their customers part of their code under an MIT license and part under a GPL license: this was not done publicly, but ONLY for code variants redistributed to that single customer. It still would apply to everyone else downstream receiving the code form the customer only IF they redistribute it.

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne So how does anyone ever actually know whether they have a GPL or BSD license? They have to check what license the person who distributed it to them has? What if they got it from a web site operated by the author who needs no license to distribute it? By your logic, they'd have no GPL or BSD license then! (And neither would anyone they distributed it to!) What you are saying makes zero sense and cannot possibly be right. And it is not right. So far as I know, you're the only person ever to argue this and I've argued open source licensing with many people.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Due to the copyleft nature of the GPL you *must* license it when you convey it. But only to the person you convey it to. The original author doesn't need a license. When he conveys the program to someone else under GPL (by attaching the license), that person then has a license and convey it to other people if they want to.

Comment: @Philipp My position was that the original author licenses the code to all of its recipients "by attaching the license". Of course I agree that that makes sense. But your position was that every distributor licenses it to their recipients. It is that position that is incoherent because there is no way to know whether your particular distributor actually did that. (And, again, so far as I know, you are the only person arguing this position. It's not even something normally debated because everyone agrees the original author licenses his code to all recipients.)

Comment: @Philipp Again, say I get the code from the original author. Unless the original author licensed it to me merely by attaching the GPL to the work, how do I know that I have a GPL license? The original author certainly doesn't need a GPL license to distribute the work, so he could have given it to me under any terms at all, regardless of what license he attached or didn't attach. How do I know that I have a GPL license if not by the fact that the original author attached a GPL license to the work? And how does that not apply to everyone?